# Popup - scroll by mouse wheel

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, mousewheel

I have a hidden div, and open it like modal popup by clicking a link. Div content is scrollable, but I can't bind mouse wheel to scroll.

I have tried this code from jquery.mousewheel.js:

```
$('#previewFrame').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    console.log(delta, deltaX, deltaY);
});
```

Comment: sorry, I found that problem is in jScrollPane.js - in plugin documentation written: 

        <!-- the mousewheel plugin - optional to provide mousewheel support -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

But wheel is working only upon the scrollbar, not the content of area :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found such solution:
Over the div with the contents lay another transparent div with "overflow:scroll", which passes caught events to jScrollPane

```
// transfer mousewheel events to jScrollPaneContainer
$('#previewHider').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    $(this).next().find('div.jScrollPaneContainer').eq(0).trigger('mousewheel', delta);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#previewFrame').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    console.log(delta, deltaX, deltaY);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#previewFrame').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.wheelDelta/120 > 0) {
            $(this).text('scrolling up');
        }
        else{
            $(this).text('scrolling down');
        }
    });
});
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5t2MN/160/)